# JavaScript and LiveView (TIBCO Live Datamart)

Tags: javascript, tibco, liveview, streambase

I have a `StreamBase` app that queries data and put it into a .lvconf table.
Is there a way to get the data from this `.lvconf` table and have it available in my `JavaScript` for me to do things with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `.lvconf` table means a data table in a LiveView server (also known as Live Datamart), the way to access data from the table in a JavaScript application is to use the [LiveView JavaScript Client API](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sb-lv/2.0.1/doc/html/lv-devel/lv-javascript-api.html). (There is [API reference documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sb-lv/2.0.1/doc/html/apidocs/lv-js/index.html) as well.)

Here is a short example of using the API to query a Live Datamart table called ItemsInventory:

```
<script src="/lv-web/api/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lv-web/api/lib/jquery.atmosphere.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lv-web/api/liveview.min.js"></script>
<script>
  LiveView.connect({url: '/lv/client/'}).then(
    function(connection){
      connection.subscribe(
        new LiveView.Query('SELECT * FROM ItemsInventory'),
        {
          onInsert: function(result){
            console.log('Got new tuple: ' + JSON.stringify(result.tuple));            
          }
        }
      );
    }
  );
</script>
```

The *Creating web applications with JavaScript* sample shipped with LiveView further illustrates the use of the JavaScript Client API for table querying.

To load this sample in StreamBase Studio:

1. Select File → Load StreamBase Sample from Studio's top-level menu.
2. Enter "javasc" in the filter field to narrow the selection.
3. Select the sample whose description is *Creating web applications with
   JavaScript* from the TIBCO LiveView category.
4. Click OK.

Follow the instructions in the sample's README.txt file to run the sample project as a LiveView Project.

Since this question and answer was created in April 2015, there is a new version of the Dashboard sample that provides a very small framework for creating JavaScript visualizations of Live Datamart query results that uses Highcharts.JS rather than D3. There is also a document called *[TIBCO Live Datamart JavaScript Dashboard Sample: A Best Practices Guide](http://t.co/crBWJ639YF)* explaining how that Dashboard sample is structured and how to add visualizations to it.

Disclosure/Disclaimer: I am an employee of TIBCO Software, Inc. Opinions expressed here are my own and not TIBCO's.

Comment: I've been looking at some the samples that StreamBase has, where they have several files including: app.js app.model.js Visualization.js... I am not understanding how these code coordinate with each other. I have written my code from scratch using your answer, but I'm having trouble understanding the way these examples are coded.

Comment: Dan -- Maybe say more about your trouble understanding, or ask a specific question? The examples are not tiny, and I suppose you could be having trouble with any number things but it's not easy for me to guess what.

Comment: Understood. The solution you gave up there is continuous query correct? Once the connection is established, the subscription will listen to the table and insert/delete/update when called?

Comment: Right, the query is continuous -- technically snapshot and continuous -- though that sample is only handling inserts as coded.

Comment: It's also possible to directly use the subscribe and unsubscribe methods of the LiveView.Connection class to use callbacks, if you are not partial to the use of then(), which is a Promise [http://modernjavascript.blogspot.com/2013/09/promise-patterns.html].